# Redirect to the same page after deleting an element

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I have a current page with a query parameter - page number:
example.com/comments?page=2
Each page contains some comments. Comments can be deleted, and after deleting a comment, I need to make a redirect to the same page. Form to delete a comment:

```
<form action="/comments/delete" method="POST">
  <button type="submit">Delete</button>
</form>
```

How can this be done in a simple way? So far, it redirects to the very first page, because the query parameter with the current page is not passed in any way when deleting a comment.

Comment: How about a query param, as in `/comments/delete?returnPage=2`?

Comment: Yeah I have already done it the same way using jquery to add a current page parameter to action of each delete form on the page, thank you!